# ServiceStack ormlite RowVersion in SQL Server

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Why does ormlite require to name my version row `RowVersion`?

Check in code looks like this:

```
var isRowVersion = propertyInfo.Name == ModelDefinition.RowVersionName
                && propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(ulong);
```

and this implementation

```
var isRowVersion = propertyInfo.FirstAttribute<RowVersionAttribute>();
```

would be much more elegant and flexible (`RowVersionAttribute` already exists in `ServiceStack.DataAnnotations`)  this would allow for usage `byte[]` as field type and would make it easier to move from Entity Framework.

Why is  `ModelDefinition.RowVersionName` constant, and not static property or lambda, at least it would be possible to use different names. Is it possible to use columns with different name than `RowVersion` at the moment?

thanks

Comment: The SQL Server **datatype** is called `ROWVERSION`....

Answer (score 1):

RowVersion is implemented as a special property like `Id` where its signature is enforced as `ulong RowVersion`, e.g:

```
public class Poco
{
    ...
    public ulong RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

This ensures that there's no disambiguation on what the signature and name should be and that there should be **only 1** such property on each table (i.e. like Id). But just like other fields you can use `[Alias]` to map it to a pre-existing column with a different name.

Using `ulong` ensures RowVersion is implemented efficiently and consistently in all major RDBMS's, i.e:

- Uses `rowversion` datatype in SqlServer
- Uses PostgreSql's `xmin` system column (no column on table required)
- Uses **UPDATE triggers** on MySql, Sqlite and Oracle whose lifetime is attached to Create/Drop tables APIs

Comment: so its by design that property-type  and name can not be changed?

Comment: @zebra yes, both .NET property name and signature are fixed.

Comment: :i have a really simple change which would work with current pattern and would allow usage of byte[] and custom names for sql-server. if you want I can send you pull request (its tiny, and seams to work). but if you think it's just bad idea to use byte[] then I will refactor my solution (I have 150 tables with RowVersion :'( and I do not want to do that. this would make life easier for everyone in future who wants to migrate from entity framework)

Comment: @zebra Unfortunately that would be an SQLServer-only solution that I don't want to promote, but if it's a small, non-disruptive change that's localized to the SqlServerDialect provider I'll consider it.